# Hibernate custom delete query multiple rows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Still new to hibernate custom queries.

My table is

```
ID   TID   R1   Position
1     1     1     2
2     1     1     3
```

I want a custom query to delete rows with TID 1 and R1 1

My current sql looks like

```
@Query(value = "delete from Table t where t.TID= :tid and t.R1 = :r1", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByTIDAndR1(@Param("tid") Integer TID, @Param("r1") Integer r1);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
```

My controller retrieves the right tid and r1 ID's.
Is it even possible to delete multiple rows at once? And where could my error be?

### Edit

After I add @Modyfying to the query i get the error

```
TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

And after i add @Transactional in combination with @Modifying i get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't where t.tid= 1 and t.R1 = 99' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you lack the **`@Modifying`** annotation, indicating a query that modify the database:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from Table where TID= :tid and R1 = :r1", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByTIDAndR1(@Param("tid") Integer TID, @Param("r1") Integer r1);
```

And yes this method can delete zero, one or more rows.

Comment: When i add @Modifying i get the error TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: I updated the answer: the actual delete must be `delete from Table where TID= :tid and R1 = :r1` - get rid of `t` param.

Comment: Add @ transactional annotation on the service layer if you have multiple db operations. -add @ transactional annotation on the DAO layer if you have a single db operation

Comment: @Benoit your comment to delete the t param actually works. But i dont understand why. t. is just an alias right?

Comment: Alias are only valid for SELECT not for DELETE. At least in MySql. Just test your delete statement in a sql console as I did and you will figure out by yourself.